# Compare arrays or other methods

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am fairly new to C#. I have been looking for a simple method to check if all the values in an array which are between or equal to lower and upper limits, these are different for each element in the array. I also run multiple evaluations on each dataset. This is the current method I use and this works fine, but I am looking to use a more eficient method. It seems that a pedicate method would appear to be along the lines of what I need, but I am unsure of how to get this to work.

There are also a couple of smaller questions at the end which lead on from this.

The arrays I use typically have around 20 elements, not 5 as here.

Column names have been changed to protect the innocent...

```
int x;
bool failed;
double [] myArray = new double [5];

for(int a = 0;a<= Convert.ToInt32(temp.Compute("Max(Col1)",string.Empty));a++)
{
    failed = false;

    IEnumerable<DataRow>rows = temp.AsEnumerable()
                                   .Where(r=>r.Field<int>("Col1") == a
                                     && r.Field<int>("Col2") > 0
                                     && r.Field<int>("Col2") < 2000
                                     && r.Field<decimal>("Col3") > 0
                                     && r.Field<decimal>("Col3") < 1000
                                   );

    myArray[0] = rows.AsEnumerable().ToList().Count;
    myArray[1] = rows.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Col4"));
    myArray[2] = rows.AsEnumerable().Average(row => row.Field<int>("Col4"));
    myArray[3] = rows.AsEnumerable().Max(row => row.Field<int>("Col5"));
    myArray[4] = rows.AsEnumerable().Min(row => row.Field<int>("Col5"));

    //CHECK 1 ////////////////////////////////////////
    double [] lowerLimit1 = {0,10,0,50000,2};
    double[] upperLimit1 = {6000,20,0.75,80000,2};
    for(int d = 0;d< myArray.Length;d++)
    {
        if(myArray[d] >= lowerLimit1[d] && myArray[d] <= upperLimit1[d])
        {
            x++;
        };
    };
    if(x > myArray.Length)
    {
        failed = true;
        dt = rows.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
    };
    //CHECK 2 ////////////////////////////////////////
    if(! failed)
    {
        x = 0;
        double [] lowerLimit2 = {6000,50,0,30000,2};
        double[] upperLimit2 = {6000,10,0.75,50000,2};
        for(int d = 0;d< myArray.Length;d++)
        {
            if(myArray[d] >= lowerLimit2[d] && myArray[d] <= upperLimit2[d])
            {
                x++;
            };
        };
        if(x > myArray.Length)
        {
            failed = true;
            dt = rows.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
        };
    };
    //CHECK 3 ////////////////////////////////////////
    if(! failed)
    {
        x = 0;
        double [] lowerLimit3 = {4000,15,0,50000,2};
        double[] upperLimit3 = {5000,20,0.75,80000};
        for(int d = 0;d< myArray.Length;d++)
        {
            if(myArray[d] >= lowerLimit3[d] && myArray[d] <= upperLimit3[d])
            {
                x++;
            };
        };
        if(x > myArray.Length)
        {
            failed = true;
            dt = rows.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
        };
    };

};  //END LOOP
if(failed)
{
    // Do stuff and things
};
```

Also is there a method to do the following without recreating the datarow object? This gives an error of unexpected symbol 'Where'.

```
myArray[4] = rows.AsEnumerable().Min(row => row.Field<int>("Col1") Where row.Field<int>("Col3") == 10);
```

I am trying to achieve the following, but using a data table is slower, which is why I use the above method.

```
myArray[4] = Convert.ToInt32(temp.Compute("Min(Col1)","Col3 = 10"));
```

And finally, is there a way to repopulate an array without a loop, I have tried array.Dispose() and array = null but they do not work. eg

```
double [] lowerLimit = {4000,15,0,50000,2};
double[] upperLimit = {5000,20,0.75,80000};
```

// Re-populate array which obviously does't work.

```
lowerLimit = {6000,50,0,30000,2};
upperLimit = {7000,60,0.75,50000,2};
```

which is much tidier than below or using multiple arrays as in the above code, as in use there are typically 20+ elements in the array.

```
lowerLimit[0] = 6000, upperLimit[0] = 7000;
lowerLimit[1] = 50, upperLimit[1] = 60;
lowerLimit[2] = 0, upperLimit[2] = 0.75;
lowerLimit[3] = 30000, upperLimit[3] = 50000;
lowerLimit[4] = 2, upperLimit[4] = 2;
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what your problem is. Could you try reducing your code down to the minimum required to reproduce the issue you are having and the expected input and output?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. There is nothing wrong with the code above, I am just looking for a method to reduce the amount of code required to do the task, and hopefully the time taken to run the code, which is simply to check if mutiple values are between upper and lower limits. I am only realy interested in what is between the //Check 1, //Check2 etc, I added the rest in to hopefuly give an understanding of what I am trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: This should probably go on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I find this code really hard to read.  myArray[0] is the count, myArray[1] is the sum, myArray[2] is the avg, etc.  Can't you rather make a class with meaningful parameters?

Comment: The point @dav_i is making is that you are more likely to get an answer if you can succintly express what you are trying to do. What should go in and what should come out. It is off-putting to answer if you have to mentally parse so much nested code to try and work out the intent before suggesting improvements.

It also seems like you are asking a second question in the bottom half. If you are asking two questions, then you should make them two separate questions :)

Again, this is just general StackOverflow guidance to make it more likely that you will get a useful answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

**1**

The values checking can be performed by use of a combination of the `All` and function and the `Enumerable.Range` function.

```
Enumerable.Range(0,myArray.Length)
          .All(x => lowerLimit1[x] <= myArray[x] && myArray[x] <= upperLimit[x]);
```

This will return true if all values are in range, and shortcut out with false the moment one is out of range.

if you use it a lot create a helper function to do between.

```
public static class MyHelperClass {

  public static bool Between(this double value, double min, double max) {
      return min <= value && value <= max;
  }
}
```

Then you can do

```
Enumerable.Range(0,myArray.Length)
          .All(x => myArray[x].Between(lowerLimit[x], upperLimit[x]);
```

**2**

Replacement for:

```
rows.AsEnumerable().Min(row => row.Field<int>("Col1") Where row.Field<int>("Col3") == 10);
```

put `where` before the `min`

```
rows.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<int>("Col3") == 10)
                   .Min(row => row.Field<int>("Col1"));
```

**3**

You just assign a new array,

```
lowerLimit = new double[] {6000,50,0,30000,2};
upperLimit = new double[] {7000,60,0.75,50000,2};
```

In some cases it can be shortened to just `new[]` instead of `new double[]` but only when the compiler is absolutely positive what you mean.

Comment: Thankyou gents for your help, I think this answers my questions.